# Why text field can not be refresh in a method?

Tags: swift, macos

I try to refresh a text field to provide information. But i realize i can not update this display till the code ends. I tried to make it async but no success. Can someone to explain me with a simple example?

I show you this simple code. The text field named txtLog only show "Nothing else" when count of i (100000) is ended. Why?

```
    @IBAction func elimineDoublons(_ sender: Any) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.txtLog.stringValue="Nothing else"
    }
    for i in 0...100000{
        print(i)
    }
}
```

Can you explain me or show me a simple example? Please...

PS: Sorry for my english, i'm french...

Answer (score 1):

You get this behaviour because your *for* loop is running in the main queue: @IBAction functions are always running in the main queue. So, you are blocking the queue in which you want to run `self.txtLog.stringValue="Nothing else"`. The UI is always updated in the main thread, so GCD (Grand Central Dispatch) waits for the end of your loop before running this code.

Keep in mind that UI components can only be properly manipulated on the main thread.

Therefore, the `for` loop must be running in a background queue. For instance, replace your code by this one:

```
@IBAction func elimineDoublons(_ sender: Any) {
    txtLog.stringValue = "Nothing else"
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async(elimineDoublons)
}

private func elimineDoublons() {
    for i in 0...100000 {
        print(i)
    }
}
```

Note that we have defined two functions with the same name, but their signatures are not the same, this is why it works correctly. Do not change the signatures, it may not compile anymore.

Comment: Hi, how can i do it properly? I'm not familiar with GCD.

Comment: I've added an example at the end of my answer.

Comment: If it’s Ok, can you please select the best answer?

Comment: Hello, it doesn't work for me. I have a long code which call any methods and i try to inform user about  software course of events in a text box. So i try to call a method to display message async like : myMethod(String:"blablabla") in my initial code. myMethod doesn't have the same name of method which is from. So i have an error...